# (Java) ideas on how to animate the cursor when it over a jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Sorry for the lousy title. It's hard to describe my problem.

I'm programming a user interface with jbuttons controlled with gaze. And I want the user to don't see the cursor moving around inside a jbutton, i.e. if the cursor is within the jbutton's bounds I want it to be/seem still.
Another way of looking this is like a 'magnetic' behaviour...the cursor should be attracted to the center of the nearest jbutton. And when it is, animate it with a sort of loading bar.

Hoping the problem was understood, the possible ideas I thought of are:
1) when the cursor enter the jbutton make it invisible and start 'filling' the jbutton as a loading bar (the goal is to click the jbutton after it has been hovered for a few seconds)
2) when the cursor enter the jbutton make it invisible and paint a running clock over it (similar to the above, but the implementation may be different)

what do you think it's more doable?

ps: I hope I will be improving the question with help of your answers/questions.